# tifffile cannot decompress JPEG because JPEG not in TIFF.DECOMPRESSORS

Tags: python-3.x, image, jpeg, tiff, compression

```
import tifffile
f = 'some.tif'
img = tifffile.imread(f)
```

Gives error:

```
~/.conda/envs/cmap_py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py in imread(files, **kwargs)
    443     if isinstance(files, basestring) or hasattr(files, 'seek'):
    444         with TiffFile(files, **kwargs_file) as tif:
--> 445             return tif.asarray(**kwargs)
    446     else:
    447         with TiffSequence(files, **kwargs_seq) as imseq:

~/.conda/envs/cmap_py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py in asarray(self, key, series, out, validate, maxworkers)
   1900                     typecode, product(series.shape), out=out, native=True)
   1901         elif len(pages) == 1:
-> 1902             result = pages[0].asarray(out=out, validate=validate)
   1903         else:
   1904             result = stack_pages(pages, out=out, maxworkers=maxworkers)

~/.conda/envs/cmap_py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py in asarray(self, out, squeeze, lock, reopen, maxsize, validate)
   3376             if self.compression not in TIFF.DECOMPESSORS:
   3377                 raise ValueError(
-> 3378                     'cannot decompress %s' % self.compression.name)
   3379             if 'SampleFormat' in tags:
   3380                 tag = tags['SampleFormat']

ValueError: cannot decompress JPEG
```

Note: It seems as though I only get the error for larger tif images. Also, the tifffile version is 0.15.1.

UPDATE-
After using pip to install `imagecodes>=2018.10.22`, I'm now getting the following error:

```
img=tifffile.imread(f)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/somename/.conda/envs/cmap_py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py", line 581, in imread
return tif.asarray(**kwargs)
  File "/home/somename/.conda/envs/cmap_py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py", line 2042, in asarray
maxworkers=maxworkers)
  File "/home/somename/.conda/envs/cmap_py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py", line 3813, in asarray
strip = decompress(strip)
  File "/home/somename/.conda/envs/cmap_py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tifffile/tifffile.py", line 3700, in decompress
out)
  File "/home/somename/.conda/envs/cmap_py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imagecodecs/imagecodecs.py", line 678, in jpeg_decode
'JPEG tables, colorspace, and outcolorspace otions not supported')
NotImplementedError: JPEG tables, colorspace, and outcolorspace otions not supported
```

On the linux machine on which tifffile can't open the large tif in `~/.conda/envs/cmap_py3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/imagecodecs` I see

```
__init__.py
licencses
__pycache__
imagecodecs.py
```

On the windows machine on which tifffile can open the large tif in `ls C:\\Anaconda2\\envs\\tensorflow35\\lib\\site-packages\\imagecodecs\\` I see

```
__init__.py
licenses
__pycache__
imagecodecs.py
_imagecodecs.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
_jpeg12.cp35-win_amd64.pyd
```

Comment: Your TIFF file is JPEG compressed, which is relatively new. Where did you get it from? What application? You can recompress it to use LZW compression instead on the commandline with **ImageMagick**, using `magick input.tif -compress lzw output.tif`

Comment: I don't know the original source of the image.  Also, this is on a linux machine.  The same version of tifffile seems to be able to open the image on my windows machine.  I've tried looking at my python libraries and other dependencies, but I can't locate the issue.

Comment: To read TIFF files with JPEG compression, use [tifffile>=2018.10.18](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) with [imagecodecs>=2018.10.22](https://pypi.org/project/imagecodecs/)

Comment: I appear to have ```imagecodecs 20.18.222``` installed but when I import it I get an error ```.../site-packages/imagecodecs/__init__.py:11: UserWarning: No Module named 'imagecodecs._imagecodecs` The _imagecodecs Cython extension module could not be found. Using a fallback module with limited functionality and performance. `\n\nThe _imagecodecs Cython extension module could not be found.\n'```  Then ```imagecodecs.__version__``` shows as ```2018.10.21.py```

Comment: I meant ```imagecodecs 20.18.22```

Comment: I am facing exactly the same issue today using the last versions of both Cython and imagecodecs. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: I didn't find an answer using tifffile.  I used opencv to open the file.

Comment: @cgohlke I installed the lastest imagecodecs and tifffile with pip install, and still get this error... Any idea what might have gone wrong ? thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same struggles as you, @user3731622

Try this code out, as recommended by @cgohlke:

```
!pip install tifffile 
!pip install imagecodecs 
import numpy 
import tifffile as tiff 
img = tiff.imread('/content/gdrive/My Drive/My Driver/imageToDriveExample.tif') 
matrix = img[:,:,:] 
print(matrix)
```